# xpath: select text nodes before and after break tags

Tags: html, xpath

considering the following : (mixture of `<br>` and `<br/>`)

```
text1
<br>
text2
<br/>
text3
<br/>
text4
<br>
text5
```

How can I locate each text nodes ?

I am thinking something that fits the condition of preceding OR following a br tag....but unsure if `<br>` and `<br/>` are treated differently in xpath.

Comment: That does not look like valid XML for XPATH to work on.

Comment: This is *not* an XPAth question at all -- your text is not well-formed XML! Learn that XPath can be used only on well-formed XML document or XML fragment.

Comment: I found your edit to be highly offensive and have reported it. I have roll backed. I think it should be obvious to you that this Xpath is not well formed, but dealing with HTML from the web, it's just a fact and need to deal with these irregular cases.

Comment: @Dimitre: See my answer which works well with this HTML fragment. I am agree on Kim Jong Woo's statement that we need to parse invalid HTML as well.

Comment: @styu: The fact remains that this is *not* an XPath question. I see that you presented a working solution and this is good. I don't know who and why downvoted you... :(

Comment: @Kim-Jong-Woo: Before tagging something "xpath" do read at least the minimum necessary to know what XPath is. This is *not* an XPath question -- period.

Comment: @Dimitre Maybe it would be enough to change the title to *How to work with XPath on invalid documents* or something like this. From this point of view it's related to XPath (XPath seems to be the best solution for this problem). And maybe Kim will undo the downvote (it was a problem with my first revision).

Comment: @styu: No, XPath starts at the point when there is a wellformed XML document/fragment. Everything before this point *isn't* XPath. As for the proposed new title -- this would best go under HTML tools. Again, no XPath is involved here.

Comment: @Dimitre, if you are really concerned about such literal dictionary technicals, than I am afraid you are mistaken. This question asked for an xpath which locates a text node meeting the following specifications: A) It's obvious this is not a well formed xml, because it's an irregular html parsed from the wild, hence a complex xpath statement is desired to locate the individual text nodes. B) It's clearly an xpath question because it is seeking an xpath solution. Looking at W3C documentation, there are plenty of xpath syntax for situations like my case where irregular formating occurs.

Comment: @Dimitre, I am quite intrigued with your agressive edits in my other questions. The point of stackoverflow is not only for the purpose of being absolutely correct but more for seeking a solution. My question was never incorrect by tagging it with xpath. The tags are meant to help other users search for similar solutions to similar cases as mine. Removing such tag, simply because it does not fit your personal mode of thinking, I find it rather childish, coming from someone who is clearly experienced, and far too knowledgable in this area to continue passive aggressive defenses. I mean no harm.

Comment: @Dimitre: If the solution is sought is clearly an xpath statement following the W3C documentation, and the solution clearly fits this question's original criterias mentioned previously, then this xpath works for this irregular xml parsed from html. If you think you have a better solution than styu's , you've obviously failed by now. Go ahead and delete this question if it satisfies your ego. I don't wish to be trolled further.

Comment: @Kim-Jong-Woo: [Looking at W3C documentation, there are plenty of xpath syntax for situations like my case where irregular formating occurs]. This statement is false. XPath only operates on the XML INFOSET, which is a representation of an XML document. XPath cannot process non-well-formed XML documents. If you have something that isn't a well-formed XML document, you have first to conver this to a well-formed XML document -- either manually or using some tool. This is not about agressiveness, just about simple, fundamental facts.

Comment: @Kim-Jong-Woo: From the W3C XML Infoset specificatio, http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#intro . `This specification defines an abstract data set called the XML Information Set (Infoset). Its purpose is to provide a consistent set of definitions for use in other specifications that need to refer to the information in a well-formed XML document [XML]. `

Comment: @Kim-Jong-Woo: Do yourself good and really learn about the things you are talking in public. Defending the truth isn't trolling -- arguing with ignorance -- is. I wouldn't delete your question -- even if I could, because it has its merit when tagged as "html". I have simply removed the "xpath" tag, because querying a non-well formed XML document isn't goal of XPath as specified in the official W3C specification(s).

Comment: @Dimitre: But we are NOT dealing with a well formed XML information set. There are many other similar questions of xpath statements that deals with malformed XML datasets if you haven't noticed. This question searches for an xpath statement which can be used to best capture the data in this irregular format. I am beginning to think you forgot to take your anti-depressants this morning.

Comment: @Dimitre, If anyone is doing a bad PR, it's you by arguing incessantly about what the dictionary says. No one cares. When you edit my questions because you fail to see the intention of the original question, you hinder the ability of other users looking for the same solution as me. They might not be thinking the way you are, They might not be thinking the way I am. I'm not arguing for literally correctness, but simply the solution that can be best described.

Comment: Okay guys, lets stop here before people start lobbing shells.

Comment: @Dimitre I also have to use xpath to search through html. To Kim-Jong-Woo: Despite not sharing your fondness of oppressive dicators, I do thank you for tagging this thread with "xpath".

Comment: @atrioom: please, ask a question and provide any information that makes it possible for people to repro your problem and to give a solution.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev This thread solved my problem due to the fact that it was tagged in what I think a pretty semantic way. Thank you for trying to help me though.

Comment: @atrioom thank you, I thought I was the crazy one. SO will do that to you over time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*DOMDocument*](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)'s *loadHtml()* method works well with invalid HTML fragments, so you can use DOMXPath this way:

```
<?php

$html = 'text1
<br>
text2
<br/>
text3
<br/>
text4
<br>
text5';

echo "<pre>" . htmlentities($html) . "</pre><br>\n";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
// loadHtml() needs mb_convert_encoding() to work well with UTF-8 encoding
$dom->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

echo "Text nodes preceding br:";
foreach($xpath->query('//text()[(following::br)]') as $node)
{
    var_dump($node->wholeText);
}

echo "Text nodes following br:";
foreach($xpath->query('//text()[(preceding::br)]') as $node)
{
    var_dump($node->wholeText);
}

echo "Text nodes following OR preceding br:";
foreach($xpath->query('//text()[(following::br) or (preceding::br)]') as $node)
{
    var_dump($node->wholeText);
}
```

Comment: this would simply get all text nodes other than the sample case illustrated.

Comment: @Kim You are right, I simply overlooked that requirement. Edited, now it works that way.

Comment: thank you, I think this fits the specification. I am also thinking of combining this to form something like //text()[(following::br OR preceiding::br)].

Comment: @Kim You could use `//text()[(following::br) or (preceding::br)]` or `//text()[(following::br)] | //text()[(preceding::br)]` for that.

Comment: @Kim Edited the answer to include it also.

Comment: @styu, still doesn't work. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280792/xpath-cannot-select-text-nodes-before-and-after-break-tags-closed

Comment: @Kim I will look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @styu, I have resorted to a different method that adds a bit of overhead but it bypasses the need for complex xpath. What I ended up doing was wrapping all the text nodes preceding and following the BR tags in Javascript with an obscure tag (like ddb). I then use xpath to locate this obscure tag. The overhead resulted in that the same Javascript code had to be executed on all pages loaded...but I guess this is a small sacrifice.

Comment: @Kim Indeed it is not working in FF, but works in Chrome (tested with [Scraper](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd)) and in PHP with DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

Comment: @Kim I think that the problem is that FF don't recognize text1, text2... as text nodes with this invalid fragment, so there is no possibility to find a working query with `text()` in it.

Comment: @styu, yes you are correct. FF doesn't seem to recognize text()

Answer (score -1):

Your example is not valid XML against which an XPath query can be run - neither of the 
 elements are ever closed.

However, generally to select that you would use the node type predicate, something like //br/text()

Comment: I downvoted this question because my definition of a good answer obviously differs from Dimitre. I downvote answers in which no solution or approach is provided and answers which appear to be more of a comment than that of an answer that results from active resolution to a problem rather than stating the obvious or reading from the dictionary. You'd have to understand the implied meaning behind the questions, and it's not always easy to get it right, and some people will have more difficulty. At end of the day, I upvote answers which helps other users pondering about the same question I have.