# How can I get array of elements, including missing elements, using XPath in XSLT?

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, xpath

Given the following XML-compliant HTML:

```
<div>
 <a>a1</a>
 <b>b1</b>
</div>

<div>
 <b>b2</b>
</div>

<div>
 <a>a3</a>
 <b>b3</b>
 <c>c3</c>
</div>
```

doing `//a` will return:

```
[a1,a3]
```

The problem with above is that the third column data is now in second place, when A is not found it is completely skipped.

how can you express an xpath to get all A elements which will return:

```
[a1, null, a3]
```

same case for `//c`, I wonder if it's possible to get

```
[null, null, c3]
```

UPDATE: consider another scenario where  are no common parents `<div>`.

```
<h1>heading1</h1>
 <a>a1</a>
 <b>b1</b>


<h1>heading2</h1>
 <b>b2</b>


<h1>heading3</h1>
 <a>a3</a>
 <b>b3</b>
 <c>c3</c>
```

UPDATE: I am now able to use XSLT as well.

Comment: Perhaps XPath is not the way to go for this. Perhaps you want to use something more robust such as JAXB.

Comment: im open to alternatives to xpath. how can you express this with jaxb?

Comment: This question -- with the update is undefined. Please, edit and provide a new source XML document that corresponds to the edit. Without providing a correct XML document, how can you expect people to guess what you had in mind? **Because you don't provide an XML document corresponding to your latest update, I am inclined to think that you don't know what you are speaking about**.

Comment: so just imagine the original html (NOT XML document) code above without the `<div>` elements, how would you use xpath to return the expected results described in this question. Please rekindle your memories at our previous discussion on using xpath for html documents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250925/xpath-select-text-nodes-before-and-after-break-tags#comment12318343_4250925

Comment: It may be useful if you were to express your goal (business rule/assignment task), without describing the expected result. For example, is the purpose to list the value of every <a> child of <div>, or null where not found?

Comment: +1 to @DimitreNovatchev and Kirill Polishchuk, I don't understand what a "missing element" means when there is no common `div` parent. Are `a`, `b` and `c` just randomly distributed throughout the document, but if there's less than 3 of them inside one parent node, then one is missing?

Comment: @Romski, yes that is correct, list all value of <a> child of <div> and when it's not found return null.

Comment: Your second case is a whole different problem to be honest, and significantly more difficult. You'd need to start with very clearly defined rules on exactly where to expect an 'a' element. I'd assume 'between `h1` elements, or after the last `h1` element' in this case, but even this is going to take a very complex xpath to do, complex enough that I'd seriously consider not using xpath at all.

Comment: `//h1/following-sibling::a|//h1/following-sibling::*[not(a)]` something like that

Comment: @KimJongWoo: Now you have my solutions to both of your problems -- my answer covers completely the second problem and a previous answer (which I can always undelete), describes the solution to your first problem. Do note that both Kirill and I deleted our answers to your first problem after you changed your question and said that the first problem was not what you wanted.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev what was your first solution? I did not see it. No, I did not say that the first problem was not what I wanted at all. I made that first problem is higher priority and the second problem as a related question. I am carefully reading both of your answers now.

Comment: @KimJongWoo: I added what I consider an adequate solution to your first problem. Again, I am still not sure what exactly should be the source XML document -- and therefore, what this problem is all about. My answer is based on my best guess.

Comment: This problem needs to be better defined (what real problem are you trying to solve).  Are we really talking about the anchor (<a>) element in HTML?  It can be in almost any place (/html/body//*/a) that there is no way to say when it is expected.  To say when an element is missing, the document needs to be constrained to a well defined schema. For example if we looked at an RSS document, we could find where the "description" element is missing because we expect it as a child of channel and item. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no null value in XPath. There's a semi-related question here which also explains this: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t686805-xpath-query-to-return-null-values.html

Realistically, you've got three options:

1. Don't use XPath at all.
2. Use this: `//a | //div[not(a)]`, which would return the `div` element if there was no `a` within it, and have your Java code handle any `div`'s returned as 'no `a` element present'. Depending on the context, this may even allow you to output something more useful if required, as you'll have access to the entire contents of the div, for example an error 'no `a` element found in div (some identifier)'.
3. Preprocess your XML with an XSLT that inserts `a` elements in any `div` element that does not already have one with a suitable default.

Your second case is a little tricky, and to be honest, I'd actually recommend not using XPath for it at all, but it can be done:

`//a | //h1[not(following-sibling::a) or generate-id(.) != generate-id(following-sibling::a[1]/preceding-sibling::h1[1])]`

This will match any `a` elements, or any `h1` elements where no following `a` element exists before the next `h1` element, or the end of the document. As Dimitre pointed out though, this only works if you're using it from within XSLT, as `generate-id` is an XSLT function.

If you're not using it from within XLST, you can use this rather contrived formula:

`//a | //h1[not(following-sibling::a) or count(. | preceding-sibling::h1) != count(following-sibling::a[1]/preceding-sibling::h1)]`

It works by matching `h1` elements where the count of itself and all preceding `h1` elements is not the same as the count of all `h1` elements preceding the next `a`. There may be a more efficient way of doing it in XPath, but if it's going to get any more contrived than that, I'd definitely recommend not using XPath at all.

Comment: with teh case of `//a | //div[not(a)]`, would that run the left side first and then the right side of the `|`

Comment: No, nodes should be returned in document order. You'd get `<a>a1</a>`, `<div><b>b2</b></div>`, `<a>a3</a>`

Comment: thank you that answers the first part of the question which I was originally more concerned about. but any ideas on the second example up there?

Comment: okay this has 8 votes...I think it's fair to choose this as an answer, I've read all the other answers but the xpath expressions listed on her is sufficient. I upvoted all the other answers below I think they are equally good but I think it's fair to say, Flynn1179 was the first to suggest using the `not()` function so at the end of the day I am using his solution. I will use the xslt solutions in the near future as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for the first problem**:

This XPath expression:

```
    /*/div/a
|
    /*/div[not(a)]
```

When evaluated against the following XML document:

```
<t>
    <div>
        <a>a1</a>
        <b>b1</b>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>b2</b>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a>a3</a>
        <b>b3</b>
        <c>c3</c>
    </div>
</t>
```

selects the following three nodes (`a`, `div`, `a`):

```
<a>a1</a>
<div>
    <b>b2</b>
</div>
<a>a3</a>
```

In your java array any selected non-`a` element should be treated as (or replaced by) `null`.

---

**Here is one solution to the second problem**:

**Use these XPath expressions for selecting the `a` elements from each group**:

For the first group:

```
/*/h1[1]
   /following-sibling::a
      [not(/*/h1[2])
     or
       count(.|/*/h1[2]/preceding-sibling::a)
      =
       count(/*/h1[2]/preceding-sibling::a)
      ]
```

**For the second group**:

```
/*/h1[2]
   /following-sibling::a
      [not(/*/h1[3])
     or
       count(.|/*/h1[3]/preceding-sibling::a)
      =
       count(/*/h1[3]/preceding-sibling::a)
      ]
```

**And for the 3rd group**:

```
/*/h1[3]
   /following-sibling::a
      [not(/*/h1[4])
     or
      count(.|/*/h1[4]/preceding-sibling::a)
      =
       count(/*/h1[4]/preceding-sibling::a)
      ]
```

In case that:

`count(/*/h1`)

is `$cnt`,

generate `$cnt` such expressions (for `i = 1 to $cnt`) and evaluate all of them. The selected nodes by each of them either contains an `a` element, or not. If the `$k`-th group (nodes selected from evaluating the $k-th expression) contains an `a`, use its string value to generate the `$k`-th item of the wanted array -- otherwise generate `null` for the `$k`-th item of the wanted array.

**Here is an XSLT - based verification of the above XPath expressions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vGroup1" select=
   "/*/h1[1]
       /following-sibling::a
          [not(/*/h1[2])
         or
           count(.|/*/h1[2]/preceding-sibling::a)
          =
           count(/*/h1[2]/preceding-sibling::a)
          ]
   "/>

   <xsl:variable name="vGroup2" select=
   "/*/h1[2]
       /following-sibling::a
          [not(/*/h1[3])
         or
           count(.|/*/h1[3]/preceding-sibling::a)
          =
           count(/*/h1[3]/preceding-sibling::a)
          ]
   "/>

   <xsl:variable name="vGroup3" select=
   "/*/h1[3]
       /following-sibling::a
          [not(/*/h1[4])
         or
          count(.|/*/h1[4]/preceding-sibling::a)
          =
           count(/*/h1[4]/preceding-sibling::a)
          ]
   "/>

 Group1:  "<xsl:copy-of select="$vGroup1"/>"

 Group2:  "<xsl:copy-of select="$vGroup2"/>"

 Group3:  "<xsl:copy-of select="$vGroup3"/>"

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (no complete and well-formed XML document has been provided by the OP !!!):

```
<t>
    <h1>heading1</h1>
    <a>a1</a>
    <b>b1</b>

    <h1>heading2</h1>
    <b>b2</b>

    <h1>heading3</h1>
    <a>a3</a>
    <b>b3</b>
    <c>c3</c>
</t>
```

**the three XPath expressions are evaluated and the selected nodes by each of them are output**:

```
 Group1:  "<a>a1</a>"

 Group2:  ""

 Group3:  "<a>a3</a>"
```

**Explanation**:

We use the well-known *Kayessian formula* for the intersection of two nodesets:

```
$ns1[count(. | $ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

The result of evaluating this expression contains exactly the nodes that belong both to the nodeset `$ns1` *and* the nodeset `$ns2`.

What remains is to substitute `$ns1` and `$ns2` with expressions that are relevant to the problem.

We substitute `$ns1` by:

```
/*/h1[1]
    /following-sibling::a
```

and we substitute `$ns2` by:

```
/*/h1[2]
    /preceding-sibling::a
```

In other words, the `a` elements that are between the first and second `/*/h1` are the intersection of the `a` elements that are following siblings of `/*/h1[1]` and the `a` elements that are preceding siblings of `/*/h1[2]`.

This expression is only problematic for the `a` elements that follow the last of the `/*/h1` elements. this is why we add an additional predicate, that checks for non-existence of a next `/*/h1`  element and `or` this with the following boolean expressions.

**Finally, as a guiding example for a Java implementation here is a complete XSLT transformation, which does something similar -- produces a serialized array, and can be mechanically translated to a corresponding Java solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:my="my:my">
         <xsl:output method="text"/>

         <my:null>null</my:null>
         <my:Q>"</my:Q>

         <xsl:variable name="vNull" select="document('')/*/my:null"/>
         <xsl:variable name="vQ" select="document('')/*/my:Q"/>

         <xsl:template match="/">
           <xsl:variable name="vGroup1" select=
           "/*/h1[1]
               /following-sibling::a
                  [not(/*/h1[2])
                 or
                   count(.|/*/h1[2]/preceding-sibling::a)
                  =
                   count(/*/h1[2]/preceding-sibling::a)
                  ]
           "/>

           <xsl:variable name="vGroup2" select=
           "/*/h1[2]
               /following-sibling::a
                  [not(/*/h1[3])
                 or
                   count(.|/*/h1[3]/preceding-sibling::a)
                  =
                   count(/*/h1[3]/preceding-sibling::a)
                  ]
           "/>

           <xsl:variable name="vGroup3" select=
           "/*/h1[3]
               /following-sibling::a
                  [not(/*/h1[4])
                 or
                  count(.|/*/h1[4]/preceding-sibling::a)
                  =
                   count(/*/h1[4]/preceding-sibling::a)
                  ]
           "/>

         [<xsl:value-of select=
          "concat($vQ[$vGroup1/self::a[1]],
                  $vGroup1/self::a[1],
                  $vQ[$vGroup1/self::a[1]],
                  $vNull[not($vGroup1/self::a[1])])"/>
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

         <xsl:value-of select=
          "concat($vQ[$vGroup2/self::a[1]],
                  $vGroup2/self::a[1],
                  $vQ[$vGroup2/self::a[1]],
                  $vNull[not($vGroup2/self::a[1])])"/>
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

         <xsl:value-of select=
          "concat($vQ[$vGroup3/self::a[1]],
                  $vGroup3/self::a[1],
                  $vQ[$vGroup3/self::a[1]],
                  $vNull[not($vGroup3/self::a[1])])"/>]
         </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
     ["a1",null,"a3"]
```

**Update2**:

Now the OP has added that he can use an XSLT solution. Here is one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
         <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

         <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="a"
              use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::h1[1])"/>

         <my:null/>
         <xsl:variable name="vNull" select="document('')/*/my:null"/>

         <xsl:template match="/*">
           <xsl:copy-of select=
           "h1/following-sibling::a[1]
          |
            h1[not(key('kFollowing', generate-id()))]"/>

           =============================================

           <xsl:apply-templates select="h1"/>

         </xsl:template>

         <xsl:template match="h1">
           <xsl:variable name="vAsInGroup" select=
               "key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="$vAsInGroup[1] | $vNull[not($vAsInGroup)]"/>
         </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transformation implements two different solutions. The difference is in what element is used to represent "null". In the first case it is the `h1` element. This isn't recommended, because any `h1` already has its own meaning which is different from "representing null". The second solution uses a special `my:null` element to represent null.

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document as above**:

```
<t>
        <h1>heading1</h1>
        <a>a1</a>
        <b>b1</b>

        <h1>heading2</h1>
        <b>b2</b>

        <h1>heading3</h1>
        <a>a3</a>
        <b>b3</b>
        <c>c3</c>
</t>
```

**each of the two XPath expressions (containing XSLT `key()` references) are evaluated and the selected nodes are output (above and below "========", respectively):**

```
<a>a1</a>
<h1>heading2</h1>
<a>a3</a>

           =============================================

           <a>a1</a>
<my:null xmlns:my="my:my" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
<a>a3</a>
```

**Note on performance**:

Because keys are used, this solution will be significantly more efficient when more than one search is made -- for example, when the corresponding arrays for `a`, `b`, and `c` need to be produced.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, this is a very good detailed answer, however it does not answer the first part of the question. I changed the question to accept XSLT solution. No one is against you here Dimitre, it's obvious you know a great deal and you have my respect, but perhaps it's somehow the slight condescending/passive agressiveness whether intended or not that really degrades the quality of your answers, I never question the correctness of them but your attitude can certainly rub off the wrong way at times, but it's all good, at the time I added the second part, it seemed to me a good idea.

Comment: Kim Jong Woo: With all due respect, it still isn't clear from your question exactly what is wanted. Forget about the time people need to *guess* what is actually wanted, but you'll get not the best answers, as you would, if the question is stated unambiguously. The fact is that a good expert like Kirill has deleted his answer and never returned back -- think of this, this probably means something.

Comment: Still doesn't address the first part of the question.

Comment: Kim Jong Woo: What first part? You reverted from the first part, causing two people to delete their good answers, and now asking for "the first part" ??? What is "the question"? You never explained this unambiguously.

Comment: Deleting most of this conversation, @Flynn, Dimitre. Please refrain from using comments to discuss voting. Information on voters is private for a reason, and this sort of useless dialog is a pretty big part of that reason.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the following, which might be rewritten to an xsl:function where the parent node name (here: div) is parametrized.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <aList><xsl:copy-of select="$divIncludingNulls//a"/></aList>
        <bList><xsl:copy-of select="$divIncludingNulls//b"/></bList>
        <cList><xsl:copy-of select="$divIncludingNulls//c"/></cList>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="divChild" select="distinct-values(//div/*/name())"/>

<xsl:variable name="divIncludingNulls">
    <xsl:for-each select="//div">
        <xsl:variable name="divElt" select="."/>
        <div>
            <xsl:for-each select="$divChild">
                <xsl:variable name="divEltvalue" select="$divElt/*[name()=current()]"/>
                <xsl:element name="{.}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$divEltvalue"><xsl:value-of select="$divEltvalue"/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>null</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <div>
     <a>a1</a>
     <b>b1</b>
    </div>

    <div>
     <b>b2</b>
    </div>

    <div>
     <a>a3</a>
     <b>b3</b>
     <c>c3</c>
    </div>
</root>
```

the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <aList>
        <a>a1</a>
        <a>null</a>
        <a>a3</a>
    </aList>
    <bList>
        <b>b1</b>
        <b>b2</b>
        <b>b3</b>
    </bList>
    <cList>
        <c>null</c>
        <c>null</c>
        <c>c3</c>
    </cList>
</root>
```